# Heat equation with Neumann and Dirichlet conditions on same boundary

Tags: pde, finite-difference, heat-transfer

I am looking at numerical solutions to the heat equation with Dirichlet and Neumann conditions on the same boundary. That is $u(x,t)$ satisfying
$$
  u_t = u_{xx}\,, \quad x \in[0,1]\,, \quad t>0\,,
$$
with
$$
  \begin{gathered}
    u(x,0) = u_0(x)\,,\\
    u(0,t) = g(t) \quad \forall \, t>0\,,\\
    u_x(0,t) = h(t) \quad \forall \, t>0.
  \end{gathered}
$$
This is with a view to solving an advection-diffusion problem with the same BCs.

If I discretise on $N+1$ points,
$$
  U^n_j \approx u(j \Delta x, n \Delta t)
$$
with $\Delta x = 1/N$ then I would expect to discretise as
$$
  (U_j)_t = \frac{1}{\Delta x^2}\left[ U_{j-1} - 2 U_j + U_{j+1} \right]\,,
$$
but then I can't see how to discretise both the boundary conditions. If I let
$$
  U_0(t) = g(t)\,,
$$
and
$$
  \frac{U_1(t) - U_0(t)}{\Delta x} = h(t)
$$
then I have an issue determining $(U_N)_t$.

Resentfully I tried discretising with backwards difference twice
$$
  (U_j)_t = \frac{1}{\Delta x^2}\left[ U_{j-2} - 2 U_{j-1} + U_{j} \right]\,,
$$
which allows me to impose both boundary conditions on $(U_2)_t$, but I think this is unconditionally unstable.

Does this even make sense? I was thinking about a shooting method using a shooting parameter $s$ with $u(1,t)=s$ to try to match $u_x(0,t;s)=h(t;s)$ at each time step, but this feels inefficient.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/20836 (or at least related)?

Comment: Short answer: This is called a *lateral Cauchy problem* and is the textbook example of an ill-posed problem (meaning it does not admit a stable solution), independent of any numerical method. There are ways of approximating this problem with a family of stable problems, such as the *quasireversibility method* (basically, add a very small *fourth-order* term to the equation, such that these boundary conditions become well-posed). But in general you should rather ask yourself whether that is really the right model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments Christian directed me towards *lateral Cauchy problems* and the fact that this is a textbook example of an ill-posed problem.

Following this lead, I found that this is more specifically know as the *sideways heat equation*. As an alternative to the suggested *quasireversibility method* (again Christian), there is a proposed sequential solution in [Berntsson (2003)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/1068276021000048564).

[Berntsson (2003)] Fredrik Berntsson , Sequential solution of the sideways heat equation by windowing of the data, 2003, Inverse Problems in Engineering, (11), 2, 91-103.